# OgreCamera.h file not found

Tags: ios, ogre

I'm facing a problem when trying to implement an `OGRE` iOS project. I downloaded and installed the OgreSDK and XCode templates from [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/ogreOnIphoneFast).

I'm getting this error: `OgreCamera.h` file not found.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the path to the OgreSDK is wrong or missing, so that the required include files such as `OgreCamera.h` cannot be found. So please double-check your paths.